# Continuous functions on (a,b)

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $a<b$. Prove that the image of the interval $(a,b)$ need not be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$

> How to prove it?

Comment: Tell me, what is $f(a,b)$? What have you tried?

Comment: One way to prove it is to give an example of a continuous function $f$ in which $f(a,b)$ is not open.

Comment: (a,b) is an interval and ∀x∈ (a,b), f(x) belongs to an interval which may not be open. How to prove it.

Comment: I have shown that f(a,b) is open but not able to show how it can be not open?

Comment: This site is MSE, not "do my homework".

Answer (score 1):

Take $f\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},x\mapsto1$. Then $f(a,b)=\{1\}$ is not open.

Comment: there also f's that f(a,b) is open. for example, $f(x)=x$. In this case $f(a,b)=(a,b)$ is open.